# Disable rewrite to https for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i use this to rewrite to https all of the calls of my .htaccess file.

I want to avoid that http://foo.myhost.com gets rewritten to
https://www.myhost.com

it should just stay

http://foo.myhost.com <-note, not even https

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a negated condition to avoid matching a subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.myhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: and for some reason i don't understand, `myhost.com` seems to turn off the rewriting

Comment: do you maybe have the time to explain quickly? e.g. whatis the ! standing for and NC and OR

Comment: `!` is used for negation of a condition and `NC` is for ignore case matching. Please refer: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html